# How to show joomla 3 user group in front end

Tags: joomla3.0

In my component front end view layout I want to make a decision based on the group(s) that the user is a member.
My code:
    `$user = JFactory::getUser();
    $userGroups = $user->getAuthorisedGroups();
          if (in_array('10', $userGroups)) {
                echo "Test Group!";
          }elseif{ ...........`

The code above shows that if there is a group id value 10, an action will happen.
Joomla assigns a number of group ids like Public is 1, Registered is 2 etc.
Is there a system call that can provide the textual value for these IDs?  The only way I currently know that there is a value 10 in the example above is to access the back end and look at the User Manager::User Groups page and visually check the value.  These values can change depending on the site and the order the groups are created.  It would be great to have a system call for the values.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just do with the User and Usergroups - it's quite easy.
All Users are connected to one or more Usergroup. And You can add Usergroups width names of your own choice. Both menu items and modules can be conditional on a specific user group is logged on to the displayed 
If You want more spcecific information, your welcome to aks.

Comment: I need to know the user group within some specific code.  Registered users can get to the menu item, but only a specific group called "tester" would get a specific value echoed to them.  In this case group 10 which is listed on the backend as "tester".  If I could do a system call and request if the userGroup == "tester" it would be good.

Comment: When using User Groups, you can control both which modules and menu items with related content that can only be displayed when a user belongs to specific User Group are logged on. It is precisely when a user logs in, the system knows exactly who and what to display.